# QProgressBar as semi-transparent overlay

Tags: qt

I have been pulling out my hair trying to figure out how to do this. I already tried using stylesheets, but to no avail. Someone on #qt said they got something like this to work, but when I adapted my code, I could only get certain widgets to go transparent, but unfortunately not QProgressbar

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QProgressBar>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QWidget *widget = new QWidget();
    QProgressBar *progress = new QProgressBar(widget);

    QPalette palette(widget->palette());
    palette.setColor(widget->backgroundRole(), Qt::green);
    widget->setAutoFillBackground(true);
    widget->setPalette(palette);

    QPalette palette1(progress->palette());
    palette1.setColor(progress->backgroundRole(), Qt::transparent);
    progress->setAutoFillBackground(true);
    progress->setPalette(palette1);

    widget->show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Just in case you are wondering why I want to do this; I am trying to have this overlay an icon of a deck of cards, that as you grab, it shrinks. I want it transparently over the icon in order to save space.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if you have some special reason not to do it with stylesheets, or if you just couldn't get it to work with stylesheets, but here is a solution for your transparency problem  using stylesheets:

```
progress->setStyleSheet("QProgressBar{"
                           "border: 1px solid transparent;"
                           "text-align: center;"
                           "color:rgba(0,0,0,100);"
                           "border-radius: 5px;"
                           "background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1, stop:0 rgba(182, 182, 182, 100), stop:1 rgba(209, 209, 209, 100));"
                               "}"
                           "QProgressBar::chunk{"
                           "background-color: rgba(0,255,0,100);"
                           "}");
```

You can adjust it to your own liking.

Comment: this gets a specific background colour however how would you get a QLinearGradient so that it matches the background it is overlaid on ?

Comment: @san Make it completely transparent?

Answer (score 1):

You can use setWindowOpacity to set window transparency, but it only works on top level windows. So if you change your code like this, it should work.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QProgressBar>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QWidget *widget = new QWidget();
    QProgressBar *progress = new QProgressBar();

    QPalette palette(widget->palette());
    palette.setColor(widget->backgroundRole(), Qt::green);
    widget->setAutoFillBackground(true);
    widget->setPalette(palette);

    progress->setWindowOpacity(0.5);

    widget->show();
    progress->show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

I don't have a qt development environment right now so i can't try it, but if anything does not work as you expect, i would gladly try to help more.